# Error in solidity code: Return argument type bytes1 is not implicitly convertible to expected type

Tags: solidity, getter-setter, getter, setter

I have setter and getter:

```
    function setFunc(bytes calldata _value) public {
        getBytes = _value; 
    }

function getFunc() public view returns(bytes calldata) {
        return getBytes;
    }
```

When I run my code, the compiler shows that

```
TypeError: Return argument type bytes1 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) bytes calldata.
  --> contracts/GetterSetter.sol:38:16:
   |
38 |         return getBytes[];
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Before that I had another error:

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
  --> contracts/GetterSetter.sol:37:51:
   |
37 |     function requestedBytes() public view returns(bytes) {
   |                                                   ^^^^^
```

Could you help to resolve it and what input example should I provide into setter for correct functions working?

I will be really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The getter function return type needs to have the `memory` [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#data-location).

It's because the EVM loads the value from storage to **memory**, and then returns it from memory.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    bytes getBytes;

    function setFunc(bytes calldata _value) public {
        getBytes = _value; 
    }

    function getFunc() public view returns(bytes memory) {
        return getBytes;
    }
}
```

---

The return type could have the `calldata` location only if it's returning the actual and unchanged calldata from the input param:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function getFunc(bytes calldata _value) public pure returns(bytes calldata) {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! What can I put to set function in case of to test? It always returns me 0x. And for Bytes32 it returns me 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: @Vlad That's an expected output. `0x` represents a byte array with 0 length (the default length of the `bytes` dynamic-length array). While the other value represents an array with length of 32 (Solidity type `bytes32`), all item values are empty (default value).

Comment: Hm.. I tried in Remix and it looks like woks as it should, but when I run it with Hardhat, it returns Zero.

```
await getset.setBytes32(
  '0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
 );

 const getBytes32 = await getset.requestedBytes32();
 console.log('Bytes32:', getBytes32);
```

Comment: @Vlad From the top of my head, it looks like you're querying a non-contract address in the Hardhat script. Please post a separate question with steps to reproduce the issue. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I tried in Remix and it looks like woks as it should, but when I run it with Hardhat, it returns Zero.

```
    await getset.setBytes32('0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000');

    const getBytes32 = await getset.requestedBytes32();
    console.log('Bytes32:', getBytes32);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).